# qsynth falied to create the audio driver (alsa)

Tags: sound, alsa, midi

Every time I try to launch qsynth I receive the error `failed to create the audio driver (alsa)`. I have no idea why it's doing this, and the internet is entirely useless. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems qsynth fails if a name is entered in `device name` under `audio` in the setup menu. Verbose event messages revealed that this is the problem.